# How can we solve for $w$ : $2we^{w^2}-2e^w=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This was the first dervative obtained with respect to $w$ from equation: $e^x+e^y+e^{w^2}-2e^w-x-y$.

We had to find the maxima and minima for which the first derivative is equal to zero and got this above equation $2we^{w^2}-2e^w=0$ which i couldnot solve to get the value of $w$.

Comment: The obvious solution is $w = 1$. With some CAS you see that there is no other solution.

Comment: @Alpha001 What is 'CAS'?

Comment: @shwetha CAS = Computer Algebra System. For example [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: @mrtauro Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it is even possible to show that this equation only has got one real root without invoking a CAS. Therefore lets rewrite the equation in the following way

$$\begin{align}
2we^{w^2}-2e^w&=0\\
we^{w^2}&=e^w\\
we^{w^2-w}&=1\\
we^{w(1-w)}&=1
\end{align}$$

From the last line we can directly conclude that $w=1$ satisfies the equation. Howsoever assuming only positive $w$ we may take the logarithm of both sides to further get

$$\begin{align}
\ln\left(we^{w(1-w)}\right)&=\ln(1)\\
\ln(w)+w(w-1)&=0\\
-w^2+w&=\log(w)\\
-\left(w-\frac12\right)^2+\frac14&=\log(w)
\end{align}$$

The LHS describes as parabola with vertex at $(1/2,1/4)$ and roots at $w_1=0$ and $w_2=1$. Due the minus sign infront we can further conclude that the vertex is a maximum. Basically we are done now. The logarithm intersects with the $w$-axis at $w=1$ and tends to negative infinity as $w$ goes to $0$. But hence the parabola has got a root at $w=0$ they cannot intersect on the left hand side of $w=1$ whereas on the right hand side of $w=1$ the logarithm is strictly increasing and the parabola stricly decreasing.
So the only possible real root is $w=1$ due the above argumentation with regard to the graphs of both functions.